# Poisson random variable with non-integer values

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution

The number of substance S in a water well (X) is a Poisson random variable with an expected value of 1 substance per liter.
As far as I know, values provided should be non-negative integers. However I am asked the following questions:

What are the values of P(-0.5 < X < 0.5) and P(1.5 < X < 2.5)?

Comment: I have to assume that there is a count of some kind in some volume of water.  Please provide the missing details.

Comment: @JimB I just rechecked, that is all the information that is provided. I added the word `substance` between `1` and `per` though.

Comment: Zero is between -0.5 and 0.5  Two is between 1.5 and 2.5.

Comment: @TheLaconic Do you mind expanding?

Comment: Is it a home work? Think of a discrete random as a special case of a continuous random variable, and use the notion of cumulative distribution function (CDF) to solve the problem.

Comment: "Number of substance" doesn't make sense; but anyway, if the expected count is per litre,  we need to know how many litres are in the well.

Comment: @Scortchi I understand the confusion as I am confused of that as well. However this is all the information that was provided. I believe the answer below is correct as I couldn't arrive to another conclusion as well.

Comment: @Aksakal This was from a statistics tutorial slides. It has no answer there though.

Comment: The answer is a standard $P(-0.5 < X < 0.5)=P(X<0.5)-P(X<-0.5)$, the CDF $P(X<A)$ is well defined for any $A$ integer or non-integer. All you need is to construct it.

Comment: Could well be. Still doesn't make it a clear question. By the way, when  your  question's an exercise, please use the self-study tag, & especially when the text seems oddly phrased use quotation formatting to distinguish it from your own ideas.

Comment: @Scortchi I'll keep that in mind for future questions!

Comment: @Aksakal could you please elaborate on how that would be calculated for a non integer negative value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X is Poisson.  X can take only non-negative integer values.  The only non-negative integer value in the interval (-0.5, 0.5) is zero.  So $P(-0.5 < X < 0.5) = P(X=0)$, which you should be able to calculate.  And similarly, $P(1.5 < X < 2.5) = P(X=2)$.

It's an oddly-phrased question.  It's possible that it was intended to confuse you.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to do that but thought I was missing something.